# What is the undici option in fast-proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-proxy

I am basically working on configuring a proxy on a API gateway, and have an issue with enabling the undici option.

The only documentation I have been able to find are:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-proxy
and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici

However I am unsure on how to integrate it, what it does and how to configure it when using fast-proxy.

Comment: We need more info on your environent and settings to help you